# Install Python 2.7.5 on Redhat 8

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install python 2.7.5 on a Red hat 8.5 machine. Right now there is no python installed on this box so its going to be a fresh install. However, I am getting into a lot of dependency issues while downloading 2.7.5. Is there a way to clean install with all dependencies?
I tried yum install with 2.7.5 rpm but getting an error

```
 Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides bluez-libs-devel needed by python-2.7.5-89.el7.src
  - nothing provides tix-devel needed by python-2.7.5-89.el7.src
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Can someone guide me through a right path to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you specifically need 2.7.5? 2.7.18 was the last release in the 2.7 line, which has now passed its end of life by more than 2 years, and was deprecated well before then. Python 3 is the present and future of the language, new projects should not be started with Python 2.

Comment: I agree. But for some reason, the application requires (as per "vendor") the deprecated version to run

Comment: Does it specifically need 2.7.5, though? There were an awful lot of bug fixes and feature enhancements that happened after that version. It could theoretically be a giant security hole.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. Trust me I put forth the same argument and lost it! At this time, as frustrating it sounds, I need 2.7.5 version

Answer (score 0):

The source for 2.7.5 is [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-275/). It's possible you could collect all the `.el7` RPMs and force them to install in RHEL 8, but then you're going to be dealing with dependency chains going right back to `libc` and other base libs, and that would probably turn out to be a bigger pain than installing everything from source. Python doesn't have *that* many dependencies, and especially if you know which modules you need and which ones you don't for your application, you can skip installing some of them.

Another option to consider is actually installing RHEL 7 so you can use RPMs targeted to that version, making dependency management a *whole* lot easier.